# How to Convert List into Unlist?

Tags: scala, k-means

i want 'clear' the **list** so, the output like this

```
(5,36,5,36,0.434, 0.36, 0.392, 0.37)
(1,28,1,28,0.457, 0.588, 0.66, 0.478, 0.358)
(1,41,1,41,0.381, 0.289, 0.433)
(5,37,5,37,0.525)
```

now i have output like this

```
(5,36,5,36,List(0.434, 0.36, 0.392, 0.37))
(1,28,1,28,List(0.457, 0.588, 0.66, 0.478, 0.358))
(1,41,1,41,List(0.381, 0.289, 0.433))
(5,37,5,37,List(0.525))
```

my code is

```
val NEWMAPPINGFILE = pFile.map(_.split(",")).map
    {
      baris =>
        (
          baris(0).toInt,
          baris(1).toInt,
          baris(2).toInt,
          baris(3).toInt,
          vektorASCII(baris(4).split("@").toList)
        )
    }.foreach(println)

def vektorASCII(pArgument:List[String]) =
  {
    pArgument.map
    {
      _.map
      {
        _.toByte.toInt
      }.sum.toDouble / 1000
    }
  }
```

any idea, how can i do that? is it possible do that? any reference or link or tutorial, would be help...
so many thanks

Comment: Can you give us the *type* of the function you want?

Comment: already solved, but thank you

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(5,36,5,36,List(0.434, 0.36, 0.392, 0.37)).productIterator.toList.map(
     x => x match {
      case ls: List[Double] => ls.mkString(",") 
      case _ => x
     }
)
```

Comment: mr @Samar could you help she or he 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715770/error-could-not-implicit-value-toresponsemarshallersearchresponse?noredirect=1#comment66734916_39715770

because i get same problem like she or he did... thanks anyway mr

Answer (score 0):

just add, very little code

```
vektorASCII(baris(4).split("@").toList).mkString(",")
```

the output just like i want :

```
(1,28,1,28,0.457,0.588,0.66,0.478,0.358)
(5,36,5,36,0.434,0.36,0.392,0.37)
(1,41,1,41,0.381,0.289,0.433)
(5,37,5,37,0.525)
```

thank you!